# Error 424 on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)and I try to run this command and I get the `424 Error...`. The code is very simple and yet I can't find a solution.

```
Private Sub Run_Click()    
  Dim Weekly As Worksheet
  Set Weekly = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly")      

  Todaydate = Range("D4").Value  
  foo = WorksheetFuncton.Match(Todaydate, Weekly.Range("A1489:A1499"), 0)  
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

I am now getting `Runtime error 1004`

```
Private Sub Run_Click()    
  Dim Weekly As Worksheet
  Set Weekly = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Weekly")      

  Todaydate = Range("D4").Value  
  foo = WorksheetFunction.Match(Todaydate, Weekly.Range("A1489:A1499"), 0) 
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:

Fixed it!

I was mising a ".Value"

foo = WorksheetFunction.Match(Todaydate, Weekly.Range("A1489:A1499").Value, 0)

Comment: @KenWhite, the line your questioning wouldn't cause an error per se. It would try to assign whatever is in cell D4 of the active sheet to a Variant called `TodayDate`.

Comment: You cannot keep on editing and changing the question altogether. It invalidates answers given below. You may add new information to the existing question if you are facing a problem with the same code.

Comment: Poor question to supply code that wont even compile

Answer (score 5):

Check your spelling:

WorkSheetFunct **i** on

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that... but I now get Runtime error 1004